# Getting error while compiling gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle

While running below command on linux, I am getting could not parse pom error. Can you please help with this?
gradle version: Gradle 5.0
gradle test Or, ./gradlew test:

> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> >     Could not resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.9.
> >          Required by:
> >              project : > com.digitate.testor:testor-framework:1.5-BVT
> >     Could not resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.9.
> >     Could not parse POM /home/roushan.ku@inignio.com/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.9/logback-classic-1.0.9.pom
> >     Could not find ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.0.9.
> >     Could not resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.9.
> >          Required by:
> >              project : > com.digitate.testor:testor-framework:1.5-BVT
> >     Could not resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.9.
> >     Could not parse POM /home/roushan.ku@inignio.com/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.0.9/logback-core-1.0.9.pom
> >     Could not find ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.0.9.

Regards,
Roushan.

Answer (score 0):

what does your build.gradle file look like? 
You need something like the following in your dependencies block:

```
testCompile  group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.0.9'
```

You can check this in the maven repository, as well as other versions of logback-classic: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.9

You also need to make sure you've specified the repositories that gradle will check , example:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```